# Product Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display my products, 3 at once and when you press prev/next it slides and show the next/prev 3 products.

My code:

```
                <ul class="upsellList">
                 <li><a href="#">prev</a></li>
//1st view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 1</li>
//1st view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 2</li>
//1st view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 3</li>
//2nd view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 4</li> 
//2nd view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 5</li> 
//2nd view       <li class="product_item product_promotion">Product 6</li>
                 <li><a href="#">next</a></li> 
                </ul>
```

My HTML is generated dynamically on how many products are in database, so dont have to worry about the prev/next button.

Comment: Set the `<ul>` width to be 3 times the size of 1 of the `<li>` items, then set the `<ul>` to `overflow:hidden`

Comment: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/ is a good website for you, with a lot of easy and free sliders.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `<ul>` width to be the addition of 3 `<li>` items, then add this to `<ul>` css `overflow:hidden`

or

Try adding the `<li>` width in `%`.

For eg.)

```
 <ul width="100%">
 <li width="33%"></li>
 <li width="33%"></li>
 <li width="33%"></li>
 </ul>
```